# error con express-handlebars en node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, express, handlebars.js

Tengo este error, quiero traer una consulta de sql con un handlebar que muestre las opciones crud deseadas.

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "links/list" in views directory "C:\Users\Andres F\Desktop\node.js-mysql\src\views"
at Function.render (C:\Users\Andres F\Desktop\node.js-mysql\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:580:17)
at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\Andres F\Desktop\node.js-mysql\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
at C:\Users\Andres F\Desktop\node.js-mysql\src\routes\links.js:22:9
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
```

Aquí mi enlace

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const pool = require('../database');

router.get('/add',(req, res ) => {
    res.render('links/add');
});

router.post('/add', async (req, res) => {
   const { title, url, description } = req.body;
   const newLink = {
       title,
       url,
       description
   };
    await pool.query('INSERT INTO links set ?', [newLink]);
    res.send('<br/><h3 align="center">Received<h3/>');
});

router.get('/', async (req, res) =>  {
    const links = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM links ');
    //console.log(links);
    res.render('links/list', { links });
 });


module.exports = router;
```

No puedo traer el handlebar a la dirección donde debe mostrarse pero aún me muestra el error.

Answer (score 0):

El mismo problema lo solucioné corrigiendo la instrucción mal escrita:

```
 res.render('links/list', { links });
```

Debe corresponder a la estructura de folders y el nombre exacto del archivo en la aplicación.

En mi caso, escribí mal el nombre del archivo, de modo que la instrucción debia ser:

```
  res.render('links/lists', { links });
```

Comment: gracias, era ese error debido a que me confundí de directorio. También le actualicé los paquetes debido a que no los leía en package.json y package-lock.json